# FIFO almost full and empty conditions Verilog

Tags: verilog

Suppose i am having a FIFO with depth 32 and width 8 bit.There is a valid bit A  in all 32 locations.If this bit is 1 in all locations we have full condition and if 0 it will be empty condition.My Requirement is if this bit A at one location is 0 and all locations of this bit A is 1. when reaches to 30th location it should generate Almost_full condition.

Help me out please.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: For Full condition i am checking with       full=(&A[31:0]),For Empty=~(|[31:0]),Almost Full =?.

Comment: Have you tried `assign almost_full = (A == (fifo_depth - 2)) ? 1 : 0`? I think it might work.

Comment: Actually here when reaching the 29 th location if all the bits are 1  it gives Almost_full.Thats ok but here before 29 th location some location is 0 .At this condition i should generate Almost_full

Comment: Suppose 0 to 30 locations are there.At 3rd location Valid bit=0 and all Locations till 29 ,Valid bit=1.At this time i want to generate Almost_full

Comment: Please share some code here or at edaplayground along with testbench.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a 32 bit vector and you want to check only one of the bits is 0. If speed is not much of a concern I will use a for loop to do this.

If speed is a concern I will get this done in 5 iterations. You can do this by divide and check method. Check two 16 bit words in parallel. Then divide this into two 8 bits and check them in parallel. And depending on where the zero is divide that particular 8 bit into 4 bits and check and so on.

If at any point you have zeros in both the parts, then you can exit the checking and conclude that almost_full = 0;